# Call overriden method from another base method

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

Say i have these two classes, one son of the other:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void someFunc() { cout << "Base::someFunc" << endl; }
    void someOtherFunc() { 
        cout << "Base::someOtherFunc" << endl;
        someFunc(); //calls Base:someFunc()
    };

class Derived : public Base
{
public: 
    void someFunc() { cout << "Derived::someFunc" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Base b* = new Derived();
    b->someOtherFunc();    // Calls Base::someOtherFunc()
}
```

How can i make the base class call the right someFunc() method?

Note: i can't edit Base class.

Comment: You would need to make `someFunc` virtual which you can't do if you can't edit `Base` :)

Comment: Also note that if `Base` doesn't have a virtual destructor, you'll quickly descend into undefined behaviour.

Comment: this is exactly what i try to avoid XD but if this is the only method i have to override even '''someOtherFunc'''

Answer (score 3):

You would need to make `someFunc` virtual which you can't do if you can't edit `Base` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void someFunc() { cout << "Base::someFunc" << endl; }
    void someOtherFunc() { 
        cout << "Base::someOtherFunc" << endl;
        someFunc(); //calls Base:someFunc()
    };
```